# How to block and unblock the media ports in MAC OSX 10.9?

Tags: macos, network, sudo, ipfw

I am working on a test project that requires me to block all media ports on my Mac OS X 10.9.

The instructions I'be veen given are "Chinese" to me :-) I have no idea how and where to start, let alone how to unblock them after I manage to block them...

Thanks so much!

Instructions available:

[User]-iMac:~ [User]$ sudo ipfw add deny udp from any to any dst-port 50000-65535
00100 deny udp from any to any dst-port 50000-65535
[User]-iMac:~ [User]$ sudo ipfw list
00100 deny udp from any to any dst-port 50000-65535
65535 allow ip from any to any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) instead of trying to figure out the commands.

HTH